# Simplifying device creation in sip.conf

Tags: asterisk

I often have to define many similar devices in sip.conf like this:

```
[device](!)
; setting some parameters

[device01](device)
callerid=dev01 <01>
[device02](device)
callerid=dev02 <02>
; ...
[deviceXX](device)
callerid=devXX <XX>
```

The question is perhaps I could avoid setting device-name specific parameters by using some variable like following?

```
[device](!)
callerid=dev${DEVICE_NAME:-2} <${DEVICE_NAME:-2}>
; setting some parameters

[device01](device)
[device02](device)
; ...
[deviceXX](device)
```

**P.S.**
It would be perfect, if there was some device constructor, so I could reduce the script to following, but, I think, that is not possible in Asterisk.

```
[device](!)
callerid=dev${DEVICE_NAME:-2} <${DEVICE_NAME:-2}>
; setting some parameters

;[device${MAGIC_LOOP(1,XX,leading_zeroes)}](device)
```

Answer (score 0):

I've had good results writing a small program that takes care of it. It checks for a line saying something like

```
------- Automatically generated -------
```

and whatever is after that line, it's going to be regenerated as soon as it detects that there are new values for it (it could be from a database or from a text file). Then, I run it with supervisor and it checks every XX seconds if there are changes.

If there are changes, it issues a `sip reload` command after updating the sip.conf file

I wrote it in python, but whatever language you feel comfortable with should work just fine.

That's how I managed that and has been working fine so far (after a couple of months). I'd be extremely interested in learning about other approaches though. It's basically this (called from another script with supervisor):

```
users = get_users_logic()

#get the data that will me used on the sip.conf file
data_to_be_hashed = reduce(lambda x, y: x + y, map(lambda x: x['username'] + x['password'] + x['company_prefix'], users))

m = hashlib.md5()
m.update(str(data_to_be_hashed).encode("ascii"))
new_md5 = m.hexdigest()

last_md5 = None
try:
    file = open(os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(__file__)) + '/lastMd5.txt', 'r')
    last_md5 = file.read().rstrip()
    file.close()
except:
    pass

# if it changed...
if new_md5 != last_md5:
    #needs update
    with open(settings['asterisk']['path_to_sip_conf'], 'r') as file:
        sip_content = file.read().rstrip()

    parts = sip_content.split(";-------------- BEYOND THIS POINT IT IS AUTO GENERATED --------------;")
    sip_content = parts[0].rstrip()
    sip_content += "\n\n;-------------- BEYOND THIS POINT IT IS AUTO GENERATED --------------;\n\n"

    for user in users:
        m = hashlib.md5()
        m.update(("%s:sip.ellauri.it:%s" % (user['username'], user['password'])).encode("ascii"))
        md5secret = m.hexdigest()

        sip_content += "[%s]\ntype = friend\ncontext = %sLocal\nmd5secret = %s\nhost = dynamic\n\n" % (
        user['username'], user['company_prefix'], md5secret)

    #write the sip.conf file
    f = open(settings['asterisk']['path_to_sip_conf'], 'w')
    print(sip_content, file=f)
    f.close()

    subprocess.call('asterisk -x "sip reload"', shell=True)

    #write the new md5
    f = open(os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(__file__)) + '/lastMd5.txt', 'w')
    print(new_md5, file=f)
    f.close()
```